# base64 image slow when send to server using form

Tags: php, jquery, base64, image-resizing

I'm sending a base64 encoded image file to server using ajax. Because I want to limit size allowed, I do resizing image and then append to a form before sending to server. But so far the performance are quite slow. Take about 10 secs to send the whole form.

Here is my code from jquery to php (codeigniter).

**JQuery: action on file input changed**

```
$('#verify_file').on('change', function(){
    attachment = null;
    if(!this.files[0].type.match('image.gif') && !this.files[0].type.match('image.jpeg') &&
        !this.files[0].type.match('image.jpg') && !this.files[0].type.match('image.png')) {
        alert('Berkas harus berupa gambar dengan ekstensi JPEG, JPG, GIF atau PNG');
        return;
    }
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        var tempImg = new Image();
        tempImg.src = e.target.result;
        tempImg.onload = function() {
            console.log(tempImg.width + ', ' + tempImg.height);
            var MAX_WIDTH = 400;
            var MAX_HEIGHT = 400; 
            var tempW = tempImg.width;
            var tempH = tempImg.height;
            if (tempW > tempH) {
                if (tempW > MAX_WIDTH) {
                    tempH *= MAX_WIDTH / tempW;
                    tempW = MAX_WIDTH;
                }
            } else {
                if (tempH > MAX_HEIGHT) {
                    tempW *= MAX_HEIGHT / tempH;
                    tempH = MAX_HEIGHT;
                }
            }
            var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            canvas.width = tempW;
            canvas.height = tempH;
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, tempW, tempH); 
            attachment = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");            
        }
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    this.files = [];
});
```

**JQuery: Appending to the form**

```
var formData = new FormData($('.verify_me_form')[0]);
formData.append('data_verif', attachment);
```

**Finally: PHP to store the base64 encoded**

```
$data_image = $this->input->post('data_verif', '');     

list($t1, $data_image) = explode(';', $data_image);
list($t2, $data_image) = explode(',', $data_image);

$encodedData = str_replace(' ','+',$data_image);

$src = base64_decode($encodedData);
$target = $dir.'/'.$verify_file;
if (file_put_contents($target, $src) > 0) {
    $result['code'] = $this->process_verification_data($user_id, $str_num, $verify_file) ? EXIT_SUCCESS : EXIT_DATABASE;
    $result['message'] = $verify_file;          
}
echo (json_encode ( $result ));
exit;
```

That's all. But it took pretty long for the json result to return to the ajax caller.

Anyone knows how to work this out?